How can a script in R call other scripts without problems with the working directories?
I have a script called Main/Main.R.In a sub folder I have Main/SubFolder/Part1.R, that reads some excels from other folder called Main/Input/Excel.xlsx.
I face the problem when I run in Main.R the line,
source("SubFolder/Part1.R")

there are some errors with the working directories.
In Part1.R, the working directory is set like this:
setwd(dirname(getActiveDocumentContext()$path))
current_dir <- getwd()
parent_dir <- file.path(current_dir, "..")
setwd(parent_dir)

This allows me to read the excels avoiding hard-coding paths.
The problem is when I run Main.R, the line,
setwd(dirname(getActiveDocumentContext()$path))

from Part1.R is now referring to Main.R, and not to SubFolder/Part1.R, and then all the excels can not be read properly.
How can I solve this without hard coding the paths?

Use the here package. Don't set working directories.

^ see https://github.com/jennybc/here_here and https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2017/12/workflow-vs-script/
